# Codable with string array

Tags: swift

This question is more of an aesthetic one. I have a simple `Codable` with a string array. I use it to encode and decode a plist:

```
struct Favorites: Codable {
  var favorites: [String]
}
```

The one thing that bothers me about this is when I e.g. add an element to the array, I have to do this:

```
favorites.favorites += [phrase]
```

Is there something I can do to prevent having to write the double `favorites.favorites`?

Comment: You could use `.append(contentsOf:` function. -> [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array)

Comment: Not sure you understood my question? I've clarified it now.

Comment: Is there a reason you need `Favorites` in the first place, instead of encoding/decoding a `[String]` directly?

Comment: @Alexander I'm such an idiot! :P I thought I always had to use `Codable` but I can just use existing types. I guess that's the real answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid writing favorites two times, you can add `subscript` to your `Favorites` struct and also add `mutating` `method` to add items in your array.

```
struct Favorites: Codable {
    var favorites: [String]
    
    subscript(index: Int) -> String {
        favorites[index]
    }
    
    mutating func addItem(_ item: String) {
        favorites.append(item)
    }
    
    mutating func addItems(_ items: [String]) {
        favorites.append(contentsOf: items)
    }
}
```

Now your can access your `favorites` array as with instance of `Favorites` struct using subscript like this.

```
var favorites = Favorites(favorites: ["Apple"])
print(favorites[0]) // print Apple
favorites.addItem("Banana")
print(favorites[1])// print Banana
```

Comment: Ah, yes, of course! That also helps me understand the basics of Swift a bit better. Thank you so much.